# Unable to write files after scala and spark upgrade

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, filesystems, ioutils

My project was previously using Scala version `2.11.12` which I have upgraded to `2.12.10` and the Spark version has been upgraded from `2.4.0` to `3.1.2`. See the `build.sbt` file below with the rest of the project dependencies and versions:

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.10"
val sparkVersion = "3.1.2"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % sparkVersion % "provided"

libraryDependencies += "org.xerial.snappy" % "snappy-java" % "1.1.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.0.8"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.8" % "test, it"

libraryDependencies += "com.holdenkarau" %% "spark-testing-base" % "3.1.2_1.1.0" % "test, it"

libraryDependencies += "com.github.pureconfig" %% "pureconfig" % "0.12.1"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.pegdown" % "pegdown" % "1.1.0" % "test, it"

libraryDependencies += "com.github.scopt" %% "scopt" % "3.7.1"

libraryDependencies += "com.github.pathikrit" %% "better-files" % "3.8.0"

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging" % "3.9.2"

libraryDependencies += "com.amazon.deequ" % "deequ" % "2.0.0-spark-3.1" excludeAll (
  ExclusionRule(organization = "org.apache.spark")
)

libraryDependencies += "net.liftweb" %% "lift-json" % "3.4.0"

libraryDependencies += "com.crealytics" %% "spark-excel" % "0.13.1"
```

The app is building fine after the upgrade but it is unable to write files to the filesystem which was working fine before the upgrade. I havent made any code changes to the write logic.

The relevant portion of code that writes to the files is shown below.

```
    val inputStream = getClass.getResourceAsStream(resourcePath)

    val conf = spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration
    val fs = FileSystem.get(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
    val output = fs.create(new Path(outputPath))
    IOUtils.copyBytes(inputStream, output.getWrappedStream, conf, true)
```

I am wondering if `IOUtils` is not compatible with the new Scala/Spark versions?

Comment: Make sure that Scala embedded into Spark 3.1.2 is compatible with 2.12.10. You can also try to upgrade your Scala version to 2.12.15

Comment: You don't need Spark to write a stream to HDFS